# Validation to check if a radio button is checked or not through javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to just check whether a radio button is selected or not through javascript. I am getting an  `object is undefined` error with the below code.

```
function ValidateRadioButton() {
  if (document.form1.optfirst.checked == true)
  {
    alert("Option1 is checked");
  } else if (document.form1.optsecond.checked == true) {
    alert("Option2 is checked");
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your ASP.net html code

Comment: Please add your HTML code to your question

Comment: Where is this code block? is it in the head or in the body?

Comment: Its under <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>Test Page/title>

Comment: And on button click OnClientClick="return ValidateRadioButton();"

Comment: Note that *checked* returns a boolean, so `if (document.form1.optfirst.checked)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your Radio button through **ID**

```
IF(document.getElementById("optfirst").checked)
{
  //Code To Execute
}
```

Comment: If the radio and the form have name attributes, how he is doing it is fine.